# Jquery AJAX to external SOAP Webservice

Tags: jquery, ajax, soap, wsdl

finally, I will start my first thread. I´m getting so many questions answered, just by searching, and that for at least 2-3 years. But now, I can´t find any answer for my question. So I guess this could also help others!

I do have a SOAP webservice on another server.

My URL I got back is: https://dummy.de/testarea/soap/index.php?wsdl

No I need to get back a XML file. I know, a cross doamin ajax call is not possible, but I found a jquery script, which makes it possible:

https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/

So, with that workaround, my code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'https://xxxxxxx/testarea/soap/index.php?wsdl',
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
               alert(xml);
       },
        error: function(xhr, xml) { 
                       alert(xml); 
       }
    });
});
```

When I debug, the var XML shows a responseText with value ""

now, I dont know whats the problem - cross domain, SOAP webservice, etc

I´m not really familar with SOAP ajax requests, so a help and information rgarding this is very appreciated!

Many thanks
Adrian

Comment: Well, you have missed to tell whether there is the error case (`alert(xml)`) or the success case (same here, `alert(xml)`), so I guess you just don't know whether or not there was success. As the `xml` is empty (I guess the alert box is empty you wanted to say), I would assume the error case. Check the error log of the server, it should tell you more. Additionally I would allow the client to give more feedback about the type of error, too, as well I would verify whether success or error is the case.

Comment: Please read the FAQ which has some pointers how to ask better questions. You will also see better answers then. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: well, im sorry to mention. this function reaches the success case, but the var xml says in ff debug: Object { responseText=""}

Comment: Okay, that's one problem less, good to know. As you're using a proxy to go around cross-domain restrictions (you do, right?), enable logging and log the response at the point where the script proxy it out. Is the response empty, too?

Comment: i´m not sure how to enable loggin, but i debugged in FF the jquery.xdomainajax.js script, and at that line responseText: (data.results[0] || ''), i can see that the data is empty!

Comment: Well one part would be to check in FF (I normally use the Network Tab in Firebug for that then), but I actually meant to log at the proxy script itself. As it shows, you need to follow the trail of the request to first of all find out why you get an empty response. This basically needs just trouble-shooting until the actual error is found. You then could ask a question if you do not understand the problem. Unless so, it's better to ask *how to troubelshoot* a specific programming problem and to tell why you're not yet able to do that. So it's more clear where the actual problem for you is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this on a local SOAP webservice?

If so it will not work, because the plugin you use goes through the `query.yahooapis.com` site to get the data.

So if your webservice is not available to the world then the yahoo api cannot access it.

Comment: this is on a server accessable from the worl. but when i insert the adress to the browser, i get that xml

Comment: copied part: <soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://localhost/pec/soap/index.php"/></input><output><soap:body use="encoded" encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://localhost/pec/soap/index.php"/></output></operation><operation name="authorize"><soap:operation soapAction="http://localhost/pec/soap/index.php#authorize"/>

so, is that ok, as the xml is on that server, so it can work with localhost!?

Comment: @AdrianHayward, nope. localhost is not good. It is set on your local network, and the yahoo domain cannot access it.. Yahoo tries to contact localhost to get the results..

Comment: ok - thanks! just to be sure. that adress from the AJAX call (https://xxxxxxx/testarea/soap/index.php?wsdl) is NOT localhost. But the xml I get when i insert that to the browser, contains localhost links. and you mean, that this wont work when the localhost is within the xml?

Comment: oh, my mistake then.. It does not matter what is in the resulting xml.. Can you post the service url ? Does it require authentication that yahoo will not be able to do?

Comment: im sorry i cant post that link - as there are confidential items in the xml. but i guess there is a missunderstanding. the resulting xml i want to get, is not that i posted above. what i posted above is the result, when i insert this url (https://xxxxxxx/testarea/soap/index.php?wsdl). I my understanding is, that with this xml result, SOAP or AJAX (i dont know) will deliver the xml file with the data!